# Propositional calculus - Prove or refute - Not a contradiction

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Could anyone help me with this?

Prove or refute:

[image]

What is the definition of $\nvdash_{CPL}$? And what does it mean about valuation $V$?
How can I prove that there is (or isn't) valuation $V$ such that $V(A)=\mathrm{true}$?

Comment: Its difficult to answer this question without more context. In particular, its probable that the CPL definition is somewhere in the book or notes you are using, and without seeing these its hard to help.

Comment: What kind of context do you need? CPL stands for classic propositional logic. I should use a Semantically Proof in this excersize.

Comment: **Not** derivable in Classical Propositional Logic.

Comment: @Mauro ALLEGRANZA I did not study this theory

Comment: By "context" I meant "where did you find the question"? (e.g. which book?) Also, you ask "what does it mean about valuation V", and we have no idea because your quote doesn't mention a valuation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\nvdash_{\text{CPL}}$ means : "**not** derivable in Classical Propositional Logic.

We can use the [Completeness Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propositional_calculus#Soundness_and_completeness_of_the_rules) : if $\vDash$, then $\vdash$.

Thus, assume that $A$ is a contradiction. This means that, for every *valuation* $v$, we have $v(A)= \text F$.

Thus, there is no valuation $v$ such that $v(A)$ is TRUE **and** 
 $v(B→C)$ is FALSE (irrespective of the truth-value assigned by $v$ to formula $B \to C$).

This, means that [$A \vDash B → C$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_consequence#Semantic_consequence), because a contradiction entails every formula.

Thus, by Completeness : $A \vdash B \to C$.

Contraposinf the argument, we have that :

> if **not** $A \vdash B \to C$, then $A$ is **not** a *contradiction*.

---

Another approach is through the [Proof system](https://www.iep.utm.edu/nat-ded/#H4) : the details depend on the specific proof system used for $\text{CPL}$.

Basically, we have the EFQ rule :

> $\dfrac {\bot}{\varphi}$.

Thus, using $B \to C$ as $\varphi$, if $A$ is a contradiction, we would have :

> $A \vdash_{\text{CPL}} B \to C$,

contrary to assumption.

Comment: Regarding your #1 approach: if v(A)=false, then v(a |- b->c) may be true or false, and v((a |- b->c) -> A not contradiction) may be true or false. How does this conclusion proves this?